# Magento 2.1.9 Back-end css not loading, the style sheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html",

Tags: magento-2.1.9

[image]I m using Magento 2.1.9 for my application.Today I noticed that after passing commands like `setup:upgrade` css is not loading for back-end while works perfectly in front-end. I checked console and find there was an error and written as Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported style sheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Ren which locale are you using on the frontend ?

Comment: no i mean to ask what locale for ex : en_US, or en_GB you have on the site ?

Comment: can you run php -dmemory_limit=10G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f command to force the en_US content to be deployed once and check then.

Comment: waiting for your image

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in pub/static/ folder and also check the rewrite is allowed on the server or not ?

Comment: no it should be the one that is provided default by magento

Comment: @ren :: Is issue solved?

Comment: Dont working this solution Atif

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145020)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145020)

Answer (score 0):

double check your file and folder permission before deploy.

first Run the following command one by one

1) chmod -R 644 ./*

2) find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

3) find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

5) chmod -R 777  var/*

4) Then deploy again bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

6) Flush Cache php bin/magento cache:flush